# Error when defining a state on navigation options

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to use a [library](https://github.com/appfoundry/react-native-multi-language-sample) to enable localization. In the sample app when I click on a button, I get an error:

```
Unhandled JS Exception: `title` cannot be defined as a function in navigation options for `Settings` screen. 

Try replacing the following:
{
    title: ({ state }) => state...
}

with:
({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.state...
})
```

I am not sure when the problem is, but I think it´s on this peace of code

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: WelcomeContainer,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Multi Language Sample App' // we advice using something static like your app's name or company name on the startup screen
    }
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsContainer,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: (navigation) => {
        return navigation.state.params.title
      }
    }
  },
  About:{
    screen: About,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: (navigation) => {
        return navigation.state.params.title
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I tried to replace the code with the proposed one but it didn't worked. Can you help me solving the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-navigation StackNavigator [`title`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#title) prop expects a string value.

> **title**
>
> String that can be used as a fallback for `headerTitle`. Additionally, will be used as a fallback for tabBarLabel (if nested in
>   a `TabNavigator`) or `drawerLabel` (if nested in a `DrawerNavigator`)

If you want to set title dynamically you can try to implement below code.

```
Settings: {
  screen: SettingsContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
}
```